# Python. Almacenar valores en un diccionario

Tags: python, python-2.7

Imaginemos que en un experimento un participante dibuja una señal:

```
Senal1_part1 = random.choice("ABCD")

Senal1_part2 = random.choice("ABCD")
```

Creo un diccionario donde deseo almacenar las señales que ese participante irá observando a lo largo del experimento. Deseo que la señal asignada se añada con valor 1 al diccionario.

```
Memoria_part2 = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0}
```

¿Cómo puedo almacenar en el diccionario el valor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer referencia a una clave de un diccionario solo hay que hacer:

```
diccionario[clave]
```

Si cada vez que sale una señal quieres sumar 1 al valor de esa clave en le diccionario solo hay que hacer:

```
diccionario[clave] += 1
```

Por ejemplo:

```
import random

Memoria_part2 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0}

for n in range(10):
    Senal1_part2= random.choice("ABCD")
    Memoria_part2[Senal1_part2] += 1

print(Memoria_part2)
```

Salida:

> {'D': 2, 'B': 0, 'A': 6, 'C': 2}