# Asignación de citas

Tags: python

Necesito realizar un programe que asigne citas. Primero pido los datos del usuario y después el sistema debe generar la cita. Todo debe esta guardado en un diccionario y en listas para que después el usuario pueda buscarse. Pero tengo un problema con el código de asignación de la cita. Tengo esto, pero no se como guardarlo en el diccionario
La parte de def inscribir_medico y def mostrar_inscripcion estan perfectas y no tengo problema

Si no esta claro, esta es lo que tengo que hacer en si

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import os
def borrarpantalla():
    if os.name == "posix":
        os.system ("clear")
    elif os.name == "ce" or os.name == "nt" or os.name == "dos":
        os.system ("cls")
        
def menu():
    print ("\n\n", "M E N Ú".center(60, ":"),"\n")
    print ("1. Inscribir al médico")
    print ("2. Asignación de citas")
    print ("3. Listas de personas agendadas")
    print ("4. Listas de personas en lista de espera")
    print ("5. Consulte su cita")
    print ("6. Archivo de información")
    print ("7. Terminar")
           
def inscribir_medico():
    inscripcion={}
    for x in range (1):
        lista=[]
        
        cedula= int(input ("Ingrese el documento de identidad del paciente: "))
        while (cedula<1000 or cedula>9999):
            print ("\nDocumento incorrecto")
            cedula=int(input("Ingrese el documento de identidad del paciente: "))
            
        nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre completo del paciente: ")

        print ("Ingrese si el paciente es de -Primera- o -Segunda- línea")
        linea= input("Recuerde escribir la primera letra en mayúscula: ")

        lista.append(cedula)
        lista.append(nombre)
        lista.append(linea)
        
        inscripcion[cedula]=lista
    return [inscripcion, cedula, nombre, linea, lista]

def mostrar_inscripcion(inscripcion):
    for x in inscripcion:
        print ("Documento: ", inscripcion[x][0])
        print ("Nombre completo: ", inscripcion[x][1])
        print ("Línea a la que pertence: ", inscripcion[x][2])

def asignacion_citas(inscripcion, cedula, nombre, linea, lista):
    """Vacunas"""
    pfizer=0 #Primera Línea - Vacunas(5)
    astrazeneca=0 #Segunda Línea - Vacunas(5)
    """Hospitales"""
    movistar=0 #Cupos (5)
    sanignacio=0 #Cupos (4)
    cafam=0 #Cupos (3)
    
    for x in inscripcion:
        if inscripcion[x][2]=="Primera" and pfizer<6:
            pfizer=pfizer+1
            print ("\nVacuna Pfizer")
        else:
            if inscripcion[x][2]=="Segunda" and astrazeneca<6:
                astrazeneca=astrazeneca+1
                print ("\nVacuna Astrazeneca")

    print("\nSelección del hospital.\n")
    print ("\t1. Movistar")
    print ("\t2. Hospital San Ignacio")
    print ("\t3. Cafam Floresta")
    lugar= int(input ("\nSeleccione una opción del menú: "))

    if lugar==1:
        if movistar<6:
            movistar=movistar+1
            print ("Sitio de vacunación - Movistar -")
    elif lugar==2:
        if sanignacio<5:
            sanignacio=sanignacio+1
            print ("Sitio de vacunación - Hospital San Ignacio -")
    elif lugar==3:
        if cafam<4:
            cafam=cafam+1
            print ("Sitio de vacunación - Cafam -")
                    
def personas_agendadas():
    print ("Función que muestra las personas agendadas")

def personas_espera():
    print ("Función que muestra las personas en lista de espera")

def consulte_cita(inscripcion):
    consulcedula=input ("Ingrese el documento de identidad del paciente: ")
    print(inscripcion.get(consulcedula))
    
def archivo_informacion(inscripcion):
    archivo=open("Informacion Cita.txt",'a')

    for cedula in inscripcion:

        linea="Cédula:" + " "+cedula
        linea=linea + " " + "Nombre:" + " "+inscripcion[cedula][1]
        linea=linea + " " + "Línea:" + " "+inscripcion[cedula][2]

        archivo.write(linea)
        archivo.write("\n")
        
    archivo.close()

def main():
    print ("\nBienvenido, usted va a realizar la inscripción de su vacuna\n")
    input("Presione ENTER para continuar")
    
    while True:
        borrarpantalla()
        menu()
        opcion= int(input ("\n\nSeleccione una opción del menú: "))
        
        if opcion==1:
            print ("\n\n", "O p c i ó n  n°1".center(60, "~"),"\n")
            [inscripcion, cedula, nombre, linea, lista]=inscribir_medico()
            print (" ")
            mostrar_inscripcion(inscripcion)
            
        elif opcion==2:
           print ("\n\n", "O p c i ó n  n°2".center(60, "~"),"\n")
           asignacion_citas(inscripcion, cedula, nombre, linea, lista)

        elif opcion==3:
            print ("\n\n", "O p c i ó n  n°3".center(60, "~"),"\n")
            personas_agendadas()

        elif opcion==4:
            print ("\n\n", "O p c i ó n  n°4".center(60, "~"),"\n")
            personas_espera()

        elif opcion==5:
            print ("\n\n", "O p c i ó n  n°5".center(60, "~"),"\n")
            consulte_cita(inscripcion)
    
        elif opcion==6:
            print ("\n\n", "O p c i ó n  n°6".center(60, "~"),"\n")
            archivo_informacion(inscripcion)
            print ("Archivo Creado")

        elif opcion==7:
            print ("Terminar")
            
            break

        else:
            print ("\nSelección errónea, intente de nuevo")
            
    print ("\nUn placer ayudarle.")

main()
```

Alguien puede decirme que esta mal por favor. Gracias

Comment: En `lnscribir_medico` creas la lista en el ciclo for, sin embargo la lista se creará de nuevo en cada uteracion, solo ponlo fuera del for debajo de la declaración del diccionario

Comment: pero mi problema es en def asignacion_citas

Comment: Además recuerda que un diccionario se compone de 2 cosas (clave y valor), lo puedes hacer así `diccionario[clave] = valor`, también podrías revisar esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38844/python-almacenar-valores-en-un-diccionario)

Comment: Si Christian, pero mi problema es que la cita no se asigna correctamente, y no se como guardarla en el diccionario que ya tengo

Comment: Tu codigo no tiene ningún error, solo llama a las funciones asi `inscripcion = inscribir_medico()`, `mostrar_inscripcion(inscripcion[0])`, y reemplaza la función de asignar por esto`def asignacion_citas(inscripcion])` y la utilizas asi `asignacion_citas(inscripcion[0])`

Comment: @anaaaasasa por favor evita ese tipo de ediciones, no solo desmejoran la pregunta y hacen que no se ajuste a [ask] si no que saca de contexto a la respuesta o respuestas recibidas

Answer (score 0):

```
class Datos():
    diccionario = {}

def inscribir_medico():
    cedula = int(input("Ingrese el documento de identidad del paciente: "))
    while cedula<1000 or cedula>9999:
        print("\nDocumento incorrecto")
        cedula = int(input("Ingrese el documento de identidad del paciente: "))
        
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre completo del paciente: ")

    print("Ingrese si el paciente es de -Primera- o -Segunda- línea")
    linea = input("Recuerde escribir la primera letra en mayúscula: ")

    Datos.diccionario = {"cedula": cedula, "nombre": nombre, "linea": linea}

    return cedula, nombre, linea

def mostrar_inscripcion(lista):
    print()
    print("Documento: ", lista[0])
    print("Nombre completo: ", lista[1])
    print("Línea a la que pertence: ", lista[2])

def asignacion_citas(lista):
    """Vacunas"""
    pfizer = 0 #Primera Línea - Vacunas(5)
    astrazeneca = 0 #Segunda Línea - Vacunas(5)
    """Hospitales"""
    movistar = 0 #Cupos (5)
    sanignacio = 0 #Cupos (4)
    cafam = 0 #Cupos (3)
    
    if lista[2] == "Primera" and pfizer<6:
        pfizer += 1
        vacuna = "pfizer"
        print("\nVacuna Pfizer")
    elif lista[2] == "Segunda" and astrazeneca<6:
        astrazeneca += 1
        vacuna = "astrazeneca"
        print("\nVacuna Astrazeneca")
    else:
        print("La opción escogida no es válida")

    print("\nSelección del hospital.\n")
    print("\t1. Movistar")
    print("\t2. Hospital San Ignacio")
    print("\t3. Cafam Floresta")
    lugar = int(input("\nSeleccione una opción del menú: "))

    if lugar == 1:
        if movistar<6:
            movistar += 1
            lugar = "movistar"
            print("Sitio de vacunación - Movistar -")
    elif lugar == 2:
        if sanignacio<5:
            sanignacio += 1
            lugar = "sanignacio"
            print("Sitio de vacunación - Hospital San Ignacio -")
    elif lugar == 3:
        if cafam<4:
            cafam += 1
            lugar = "cafam"
            print("Sitio de vacunación - Cafam -")
    else:
        print("La opción escogida no es válida")

    Datos.diccionario["vacuna"] = vacuna
    Datos.diccionario["lugar"] = lugar

lista = inscribir_medico()
mostrar_inscripcion(lista)
asignacion_citas(lista)
```

Tu código está muy bien, pero recuerda llamar a las funciones que defines, sino no se muestra nada.

Al escribir `return cedula, nombre, linea` el resultado de llamar a la función `inscribir_medico()` es una lista con los valores de esas 3 variables.

Con `lista = inscribir_medico()` guardas esa lista para posteriormente llamar a las otras dos funciones pasando la lista como parámetro.

Comment: pero el diccionario donde esta??, es que despues tengo que hacer un punto en el que el usuario digita la cedula y salen todos sus datos

Comment: Haces otra función que sea `getDatos` y pides que digital el documento de identidad y buscas tal registro en el diccionario

Comment: Yo no subi el codigo completo, porque el programa lo estoy trabajando con un menu

Comment: Entonces las funciones las llame al final

Comment: He incluido el diccionario en la clase `Datos` para que puedas acceder a él desde cualquier parte del código escribiendo `Datos.diccionario`

Comment: @Angel  Ya coloque el codigo completo, pero no se como hacer para que el lugar de vacunacion y la vacuna se guarden en el diccionario "inscripcion"

Comment: Es muy simple, lo he añadido en el código. `Datos.diccionario["vacuna"] = vacuna` y `Datos.diccionario["lugar"] = lugar`